# Deslice hacia arriba animación en Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

¿Cómo puedo animar una `StackView` para que se deslice hacia arriba comenzando desde `x=0` hasta `y=500`? Tengo el siguiente método en `viewDidLoad()` que hace un efecto que crece el `StackView`:

```
StackView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0, 0.0)
```

y luego añadí un efecto creciente en el método `viewDidAppear()`:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
    self.StackView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
}, completion: nil)
```

Después el método ejecuta el `viewDidLoad` y el `StackView` se reduce al tamaño mínimo. Cuando el método de `viewDidLoad` se completa, el método `viewDidAppear` se invoca, y comienza la animación y el `StackView` comienza a crecer. La animación se detiene cuando el `StackView` llega a su tamaño original.

Aunque es un buen efecto, no es lo que quiero lograr. Quiero que la animación se deslice desde `x= 0` y se detenga en `y=500`. Traté de añadir el siguiente código en el `viewDidLoad` para lograrlo, pero sigo teniendo el mismo efecto creciente:

```
StackView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 500)
```

¿Alguna sugerencia sobre cómo lograr esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo establecería unas `constraints` que definan la posición inicial del `stackview`, por ejemplo `bottomConstraint` y `leadingConstraint`.

El `leading` lo puedes dejar con el valor final, ya que si te he entendido bien, quieres animar el eje Y.

así en `viewDidLoad` podrías animar el cambio de la constraint `bottomConstraint`

Suponiendo que tu stackview tiene una altura de 200, define tu `bottomConstraint` en el storyboard con un valor de -200, para que quede fuera de la pantalla.

[image: captura constraint][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.bottomConstraint.constant = 500
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

Luego ya puedes jugar con los valores como quieras para alcanzar el efecto deseado.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que quieres es que cuando deslizas para arriba empieza la animación no?

```
func slideInFromUP(duration: NSTimeInterval = 1.0, completionDelegate: AnyObject? = nil) {
    // Create a CATransition animation
    let slideInFromUPTransition = CATransition()

    // Set its callback delegate to the completionDelegate that was provided (if any)
    if let delegate: AnyObject = completionDelegate {
        slideInFromUPTransition.delegate = delegate
    }

    // Customize the animation's properties
    slideInFromUPTransition.type = kCATransitionPush
    slideInFromUPTransition.subtype =  kCATransitionFromTop
    slideInFromUPTransition.duration = duration
    slideInFromUPTransition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    slideInFromUPTransition.fillMode = kCAFillModeRemoved

    // Add the animation to the View's layer
    self.layer.addAnimation(slideInFromUPTransition, forKey: "slideInFromUPTransition")
}
```

Intenta con esto aver si hace lo que tu necesitas.